# Apache TIKA detects wrong content type

Tags: spring, jax-rs, apache-tika

I am using spring JAX-RS to upload file as a multipart form-data.  I have inputstream object as an argument. I get my text file  when I copy this input stream to disk.

but when I try to detect content type of this Input stream, I get Content Type as application/octet-stream.

My code is

```
    Tika tika = new Tika();
    String contentType = tika.detect(in);
```

`in` is my `InputStream` object and I am getting content type as `application/octet-stream`.

As a test I also tested the same file with tika desktop, and i got the right content type `text/plain`.

Answer (score 3):

Detecting a text file as a text file is actually hard...there are no magic bytes. Tika relies on the filename (file suffix) if it is provided.  If you run detect on a File or if you pass in the file name detect(InputStream is, String filename) or if you pass in the file name in the Metadata object (metadata.set(Metadata.RESOURCE_NAME_KEY, fileName)), you'll get the correct results.

Comment: even the filename doesn't have any clue of the format. file extension is .xyz